# API to get Wikipedia revision id by date

Tags: api, date, wikipedia, revision, wikipedia-api

Is there any API to get wikipedia revision id by date, instead of checking all the revision history and extract out the most recent revision before that date?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The [revision query api](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions) allows you to pass timestamps to get only revisions from a specified interval. Use

```
api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvstart= myTimestamp
```

Check out the [Manual:WfTimestamp](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:WfTimestamp) for accepted formats - `yyyymmddhhmmss` always works.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer:
The always accepted format `yyyymmddhhmmss` returned errors.
This example returned a valid response:

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Geek&rvprop=ids&rvlimit=1&rvstart=2016-12-01T00%3A00%3A00.000Z)

[XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&titles=Geek&rvprop=ids&rvlimit=1&rvstart=2016-12-01T00%3A00%3A00.000Z)

The id in field revid contains the id previous to the date passed in param rvstart:

[Revision id](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Geek&oldid=751538469)