# Wikipedia: When were links added?

Tags: hyperlink, history, wikipedia, revision

I would like to know how to extract all the Wikipedia links that were added and removed within a time window for a specific article in Wikipedia.

So far I know how to extract Wikipedia revisions in this questions: [How to get full Wikipedia revision-history list from some article?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411896/get-full-wikipedia-revision-history-list-from-some-article)
And how to  do it for a specific time window: [API to get Wikipedia revision id by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906739/is-there-any-api-to-get-wikipedia-revision-id-by-date-instead-of-checking-all-t)

For example, here is how I obtain the content of the revision for a time window for the article Germanwings_Flight_9525 :
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvlimit=500&titles=Germanwings_Flight_9525&rvstart=20150325180000&rvend=20150323180000&rvprop=ids|timestamp|content

How to obtain the links added and removed?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide code snippets that you have worked out so far.

Comment: I haven't worked any code yet, I am trying to see if there is an easy solution to obtain the links only (without too much regex code).

Comment: Give us example for *'link'*, because there are several types of Wikipedia links

Comment: Hi, I resolved my problem using the following type of request : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=some_text&contentmodel=wikitext&format=json&prop=links    The problem that I am having now is that I get an error when the text is too long. I have read that I have to do a POST REQUEST to solve it, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve all the revisions, split them by "[[" and look for the next "|" or "]" character. With that you find all the links, which you can collect in a list or something in order to recognize new ones.